# How to retrieve number of records returned from firestore where query in python?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the number of records returned by a query in my Firebase collection but I cannot retrieve the number of records returned from the query.

```py
from google.cloud import firestore as cloud_firestore
firestore = cloud_firestore.Client()
posts_ref = firestore.collection('posts')
docs = posts_ref.where('slug', '==', post['slug']).stream()  # The is an iterable which can be looped over
# This throws an error; TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
if len(docs) != 0:
    print("Post already exists!")
    exit()

# add_post_to_db()...
```

Please someone help me how to get the number of records returned from this query. I'm having a hard time with this.

Comment: docs.len, docs.size, docs.size(), ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to convert **generator** to **list**

```py
docs = list(posts_ref.where('slug', '==', post['slug']).stream())
```

Comment: Or you can use get() method instead of stream(). It directly returns a list of docs.

Answer (score 0):

#### 2023 update

If you don't need to read **inside** the documents but just want to know **how many** there are, you can use the `count()` method which performs an aggregation query. It is way more fast and cheaper.

You need `firebase-admin>=6.1.0`.

```
from firebase_admin import firestore
db = firestore.client()
# here you may need to perform the usual auth stuff


posts_ref = firestore.collection('posts')
query = posts_ref.where('slug', '==', post['slug'])
result = query.count().get()
print("Nb docs in query:", result[0][0].value)
```